# Remove all specific classes inside a table

Tags: jquery

Hello I need to remove all the `entry-selected` class avaialable in my table rows. This is my html structure:

```
<table border='1' id='resource-container' style="margin-top: 10px; height: 396px; width: 100%;">
                <tr id="res-1" class='entry entry-selected'><td style="background-color:#FFCCC2" class="resource-color">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style="padding-left: 10px"><div><strong>foo</strong><br>test</div></td></tr>
                <tr id="res-1" class='entry'><td style="background-color:#F41FF2" class="resource-color">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style="padding-left: 10px"><div><strong>foo</strong><br>test</div></td></tr>
                <tr id="res-1" class='entry'><td style="background-color:#F4CCC2" class="resource-color">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style="padding-left: 10px"><div><strong>foo</strong><br>test</div></td></tr>
                </table>
```

Actually I tried this:

```
 $('#resource-container').removeClass('.entry-selected')
```

but this doesn't remove the class for each element that have this. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate the rows and remove the class from any row with the class.

```
$.each($('#resource-container tr'), function(idx, val) {
  $(this).removeClass('entry-selected');
});
```

Comment: `$.each` is redundant here.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$('#resource-container').find('.entry-selected').removeClass('entry-selected')
```

This will remove all `entry-selected` classes within the table. Not only on the table rows.

**Updated**

To remove the class only on `<tr>` you can do:

```
 $('#resource-container').find('tr.entry-selected').removeClass('entry-selected')
```

Answer (score 3):

You must address the correct elements in your code. You are now removing it from the table element:

```
 $('#resource-container tr.entry-selected').removeClass('entry-selected')
```

The above should do the trick. It now selects all `tr` children of the table that have `entry-selected` as classname.

-- optimised thanks to [Rory McCrossan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#resource-container tr.entry').removeClass("entry-selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border='1' id='resource-container' style="margin-top: 10px; height: 396px; width: 100%;">
                <tr id="res-1" class='entry entry-selected'><td style="background-color:#FFCCC2" class="resource-color">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style="padding-left: 10px"><div><strong>foo</strong><br>test</div></td></tr>
                <tr id="res-1" class='entry'><td style="background-color:#F41FF2" class="resource-color">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style="padding-left: 10px"><div><strong>foo</strong><br>test</div></td></tr>
                <tr id="res-1" class='entry'><td style="background-color:#F4CCC2" class="resource-color">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td style="padding-left: 10px"><div><strong>foo</strong><br>test</div></td></tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, even a better optimalisation!